# How to get current user data in django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get logged user data but I get an only username

I try these codes

```
 user= User.objects.get(id=user_id)
 user= User.objects.filter(id=emp_data.user_id).first()
 user =request.user
```

this 3 query returns username

how can i get user details

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
print(user.__dict__)
```

This`ll give you all attributes of User class

Answer (score 0):

These queries don’t return the username they actually return a User object. You can access the object attributes like user.name user.email etc

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using `print()` function to print the object, hence you are seeing the username. This username comes from this implementation (source on [GitHub](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e96320c91724830034033a9cb8afd9cf8c11e2fd/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L71)):

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.get_username()
```

Where `get_username()` method returns username, and print executes `__str__` function. If you want to see more properties or methods of the object, either use `print(dir(user))` or debug using your IDE (or with `pdb`). You can see the type of object by `type(user)` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
def user_information(request, pk):
    user_infor = get_objects_or_404(User, id=pk)
    return render(request, 'infor.html', {'user_infor':user_infor})
```

And in your infor.html you can get user information by:

```
<p>{{user_infor.user.email}}</p>
<p>{{user_infor.user.username}}</p>
```